# Setting BIOS/UEFI Administrator Password from Linux CLI

Tags: linux, boot, bios, passwords

is there a way to set the BIOS/UEFI Administrator password from a Linux CLI for a BIOS/UEFI that doesn't has any password set?

I'm trying to automate the process of provisioning some servers and wanted to avoid having to go to the BIOS/UEFI manually to set the admin password.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Motherboard firmware is not OS accessible _(even if it was hypothetically possible, it would create an insecure system, allowing BIOS/UEFI firmware changes remotely)_

Answer (score 0):

No, because Linux can't access BIOS, because BIOS is a separate chip.

Comment: As it is possible to update the UEFI Secure Boot certs with linux tools such as efi-updatevars I thought there could be a way to change the admin password as well. Thank you for your response.